# Swing : Object cannot be converted to String

Tags: java, swing

I have a conversion problem; my variable CodeA is of type String

```
col.setCodeA((Collabo)jComboBoxAlbum.getSelectedItem());
```

My error message is that `Object cannot be converted to String`
In this case how to convert my variable CodeA?

```
Collabo col = new Collabo();
        col.setCodeA((Collabo)jComboBoxAlbum.getSelectedItem());
        boolean ok = daoCol.insertCollabo(col);
        if (!ok)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Insertion impossible !","Avertissement",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        this.dispose();
```

Here is my class Collabo:

```
public class Collabo {
    private String codeA;
    private Musicien mutApp;
    private Instrument insApp;


    public Collabo(String codeA, Musicien mutApp, Instrument insApp) {
        this.codeA = codeA;
        this.mutApp = mutApp;
        this.insApp = insApp;
    }

    public String getCodeA() {
        return codeA;
    }

    public void setCodeA(String codeA) {
        this.codeA = codeA;
    }

    public Musicien getMutApp() {
        return mutApp;
    }

    public void setMutApp(Musicien mutApp) {
        this.mutApp = mutApp;
    }

    public Instrument getInsApp() {
        return insApp;
    }

    public void setInsApp(Instrument insApp) {
        this.insApp = insApp;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return codeA;
    }
```

Comment: Maybe try to first store the selected item from the combo box into a variable defined explicitly as String and then use setCodeA with the newly made variable?

Comment: So how do you want the conversion from `Collabo` to `String` to work?  Will the `toString` method in `Collabo` do what you want?  If so, can you just call it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your jComboBoxAlbum contains objects of type Collabo (since you cast the result to that type), and that you want to set the string of the new Collabo instance to the same as the string in the selected item, just call the selected item's getCodeA() method:

```
Collabo col = new Collabo();
Collabo selected = (Collabo)jComboBoxAlbum.getSelectedItem();
col.setCodeA(selected.getCodeA);
```